# I cant break blocks in minecraft (i know you hold to break)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This morning i got on minecraft and it wouldnt let me break anything. I know you hold the blocks to break them but it switches to the 1st item  i have in my inventory. I dont know if its a glitch or what. But please try to help me.

Comment: We can't exactly help you much unless you add more of the details. What operating system? What version of Minecraft? *Any mods installed*?

Comment: I think this is more of a technical issue.  When you do hold down the mouse button, how does the block you're trying to remove react?  Does it just keep reseting to the first break frame (with the small break dot in the center) or does it break and reappear?  Since your hand is also jumping to Slot1, was there any resent mods installed?

Comment: Are you in adventure mode?